# cocoa framework in carbon class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I am writing Contextual Menu Plugins for Leopard OS and referring [SampleCMPlugIn](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#samplecode/SampleCMPlugIn/Introduction/Intro.html). its working fine. Now i want to call cocoa function from this plugin but when i am adding cocoa framework into my project and including into source file i am getting 10874 errors like.

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:126:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:126: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token


/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:127:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:127: error: expected ')' before '*' token


/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:129:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:129: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
```

**EDIT:**

when i change my source code file extension from .c to .mm as suggested by [Michael Dautermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981049/michael-dautermann) , i got 5 errors:

```
/Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:826:0 /Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:826: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const __CFUUID*'


/Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1228:0 /Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1228: error: jump to label 'SampleSubMenu_Create_Complete_fail'


/Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1140:0 /Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1140: error:   from here


/Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1143:0 /Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1143: error:   crosses initialization of 'int disableMainMenu'


/Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1142:0 /Users/path/SampleCMPlugIn.mm:1142: error:   crosses initialization of 'int count'
```

can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Check out the yellow box that appears when you open that legacy [SampleCMPlugin page](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#samplecode/SampleCMPlugIn/Introduction/Intro.html) that you mentioned:

> Important: The information in this document is obsolete and **should not
>   be used for new development**. Links to downloads and other resources
>   may no longer be valid.

Carbon is deprecated and more importantly, the code you're writing is likely to not be compatible with 64-bit OS'es (in which case it won't get loaded by the Finder).

A good alternative would be to use [Services menus](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).

I also just Googled up [this ad for a product called Abracode Shortcuts](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/macosx_10_6_snow_leopard_and_contextual_menu_plugins.html) which appears to be a free thing.

Comment: I am working on leopard os and that code is working fine on leopard os. is there any way to call cocoa function?

Comment: I guess you're certain you want to keep going with what you are doing. If the file extension of your code (where you want to call the Cocoa function) is .c or .cpp, change it to .mm (for Objective C++) and see if the compiling problems go away.  If they don't, modify your question to include screenshots of what the project window looks like, so we can see how you are including your frameworks.

Comment: I have only SampleCMPlugIn.c file, i changed SampleCMPlugIn.c extension to .mm , now i am getting 5 errors.

Comment: well that's much better, yes?  Fix those errors and you will be all set.

Comment: @jennifer: It may be working fine on Leopard, but don't expect it to work in later OSs. I'm pretty sure it was Snow Leopard that introduced the Cocoa Finder—and, in so doing, killed off the old Contextual Menu Plug-ins.

Comment: @PeterHosey thank you for you suggestion. I am using this in leopard os because i want to  show my contextual menu item above Label.